# Favicon not showing up, even when checking direct URL to favicon file

Tags: image, .htaccess, favicon

I have a favicon file that won't show up on my site.
At first I thought it might be the htaccess that's to blame, but I'm not sure if that's the right direction.

My htaccess is set to send the URL to index.php for parsing:

```
#Pass to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(css|gif|jpe?g|png|txt|xml|js|pdf|html)$ /home/username/public_html/domain.com/index.php [NC,L]

#Hotlinking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com(/)?.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpe?g|bmp|png|ico|css|js|pdf)$ http://domain.com [R,NC]
```

And I have the following HTML:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://domain.com/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://domain.com/favicon.ico" />
```

When I try to access the favicon.ico file directly, the image doesn't load at all.  When I try opening the image file locally (from my hdd, using chrome or firefox) it opens and shows up fine.

Comment: The favicon returned has zero bytes. I think something went wrong when uploading. Don't see how the htaccess would cause this. But you could try temporarily removing all the htaccess and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Gerben I tried correcting for both of your notes - re-uploaded the favicon file and also removed the htaccess file, but there was no change.

Comment: What filesize does your ftp client give you for this file. Try renaming it to something else like `icon.ico` or even 'icon.txt' and see if you get something outputted in your browser (also try without htaccess).

Comment: @Gerben It's about 2kb when I check the file.  Somehow, renaming the file to favicon.txt via FTP, and then renaming it again to favicon.ico (also in FTP) seemed to do the trick.  I'm now able to load the icon directly and see it show up as a favicon in the browser.  Not sure how that happened....

Comment: Me neither, but if it work, it work. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see comments (above) for solution/workaround.